# How to setup MQSeries in Perl

Tags: perl, unix, ibm-mq

I am assigned with placing request messages to Websphere MQ queue and listening to response queue for response message using perl script.

I have experience in MQ but not in Perl scripting ..

I googled on perl modules found some thing called "CPAN mqseries module" can be used to integrate WBI MQ.

However I don't have any idea how to setup that in my unix environment.
I gave following links to my unix team

- [MQ-Series-1.34](http://search.cpan.org/~mqseries/MQSeries-1.34/)
- [App-cpanminus-1.7040](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/App-cpanminus-1.7040/lib/App/cpanminus.pm)

Even my unix team here don't have any idea about setup and they were asking "whether software is having RPM package or AIX binaries" .. but I don't see them any where.
They don't have any idea on how to setup using CPAN.

I tried copy all the .pm files from `mqseries.1.34` which I downloaded from above links under `/usr/opt/perl/5.8.8/lib/` how getting following error while trying to call some sample perl which just loads the modules.

Here I attached my sample script.

```
package myMQModule;

use strict;
use warnings;

use MQSeries;
use MQSeries::QueueManager;
use MQSeries::Queue;
use MQSeries::Message;


1; # end with a true value
```

getting following error while running above script`

```
"functions" is not defined in %MQSeries::EXPORT_TAGS at /usr/opt/perl5/lib/5.8.8/aix-thread-multi/MQSeries/QueueManager.pm line 20
Can't continue after import errors at /usr/opt/perl5/lib/5.8.8/aix-thread-multi/MQSeries/QueueManager.pm line 20
BEGIN failed–compilation aborted at /usr/opt/perl5/lib/5.8.8/aix-thread-multi/MQSeries/QueueManager.pm line 20
```

**So I need help in how to setup `mqseries` module in my unix environment and is there any guide to do the same.
You help highly appreciated ..
Please help !!!!**

Answer (score 0):

Best not to install Perl modules manually. You've found cpanminus, that's a good tool for installing modules for you, but you need to install it first. From the [metacpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus#Installing-to-system-perl) site here are the instructions to install cpanminus:

```
curl -L https://cpanmin.us | perl - --sudo App::cpanminus
```

Note, it does require superuser privileges.

Once you've installed cpanminus use it to install your MQSeries modules correctly from the shell:

```
cpanm MQSeries
cpanm MQSeries::QueueManager
etc
```

If there are any dependencies cpanminus will deal with those for you.

Note: Some modules have binary components and may require dev tools (gcc etc) to build them.

Moving on to your script. What you've written there is a module, and not a script. If you write a script to "use" your module you'll be able to put functions in the module and call them from your script, something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use myMQModule;

my $ret_val = myMQModule::some_func();
.
.
```

I think you need to start by making sure your modules are installed correctly by installing cpanm and trying to install the modules with that, if the module is correctly installed it will report that you have the latest version and do no more.

Comment: Hi Justin, My environment not allowed to connect, even if I install cpan its of no use for me. I tried to install cpan.. but its asking for ftp proxy, http proxy etc.. which is not allowed in our environment. I need to install those modules manually but when I tried to install its giving lot of pre requisites ..  not sure whether we have any document to understand and istall all of them